# Why does a business with an ROIC greater than its NOPAT growth rate means that the business is "generating excess cash"

Tags: investing

In Michael Mauboussin's "Capital Allocation" paper (https://www.morganstanley.com/im/publication/insights/articles/article_capitalallocation.pdf) he frequently references the idea that a business with an ROIC greater than its NOPAT growth rate means that the business is "generating excess cash". Could anyone explain why this implication is true? That is, I don't see the connection on how A (ROIC > NOPAT growth) necessarily implies B (business is generating excess cash) here. Could anyone clarify this for me? Perhaps with some kind of mathematical proof to illustrate this plainly?

E.g.

> Capital allocation is an important investment issue because the aggregate ROIC for public companies exceeds the aggregate growth rate This means that businesses generate excess cash

*It may be important to note that Mauboussin does not include cash in his definition of Invested Capital.

This is what I have so far:

```
Assume we know the IC[t=0], NOPAT growth rate = gN, and ROIC[t=0] > gN > 0.
After 1yr, NOPAT[1] = NOPAT[0] + (NOPAT[0] x gN).
To just maintain ROIC[1] = ROIC[0], incremental IC, IIC, would need to be the solution to...
(NOPAT[0] + (NOPAT[0] x gN)) / (IC[0] + IIC) = NOPAT[0] / IC[0]
==> IIC = IC[0] x gN
```

We then need to prove that (NOPAT[0] + (NOPAT[0] x gN)) > IIC in order to imply excess capital left over (NOPAT[0] + (NOPAT[0] x gN)) - IIC > 0) in a constant ROIC situation. That is...

```
If n/c > g > 0, prove that (n + n*g) > c*g
```

... At this point I'm stuck (and IDK that this can even be proven or is solvable given that we also would hold that n > 0 and c > 0 as well)

To put it another way...

```
Given:
1 >= ROIC[t=0] > gN > 0
IC[t=0]

After 1yr (t=1):
NOPAT[1] = NOPAT[0] x (1 + gN) = NOPAT[0] + NOPAT[0] x gN
To maintain same ROIC...
ROIC[1] = ROIC[0]
==> ROIC[1] = NOPAT[1] / (IC[0] + IIC) = (NOPAT[0] + NOPAT[0] x gN) / (IC[0] + IIC) = NOPAT[0] / IC[0] = ROIC[0]
==> IIC (the incremental invested capital to maintain ROIC given we generated NOPAT[t=1]) is whatever solves...
(n+ng) / (c+i) = n/c for i
==> IIC = IC[0] x gN
If IIC < NOPAT[1], then there is excess capital (ie. not all NOPAT[t=1] had to be reinvested to maintain constant ROIC ratio)

We are thus seeking to prove that the case where 1 >= ROIC[t=0] > gN > 0 must imply IIC < NOPAT[1]
... ie. 1 >= n/c > g > 0 ==> c*g < n + n*g
```

*The reason I'm trying to proof this out is because Mauboussin seems to take it 1) for granted and 2) as a generality in that paper, so I'm trying to see it proved out as a generality myself.

For now I simply accept it as *provable somehow* because [Wolfram Alpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bn%2Cc%5D%20%3E%20g%20%3E%200%5C%2844%29%20c*g%20%3C%20n%20%2B%20n*g%5C%2844%29%20c%3E0%5C%2844%29%20n%3E0) that final set of inequalities has the solutions space of `c>0, g>0, n>c*g`, ie. `IC[t=0] > 0, gN > 0, ROIC[t=0] > gN` (that last inequality being the thing I'd want to prove).

*I think I was stuck in the previous equations because I actually wrote the last inequality backwards (which I've edited now), so was trying to "prove" the wrong thing.